# Input incompatible with layers - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer

I'm currently facing a problem with Tensorflow library that I couldn't resolve. All solutions I've already found on stackoverflow didn't help me understanding the real problem.

```
def build_model(dim_data, n_neurons):

model = tf.keras.Sequential(name="Reseau_de_neurones")

model.add(layers.Dense(units = n_neurons, input_shape=(3, 1), bias_initializer="glorot_uniform")) 
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Dense(units = n_neurons, input_shape=(dim_data,), bias_initializer="glorot_uniform")) 
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Dense(units = n_neurons, input_shape=(dim_data,),  bias_initializer="glorot_uniform")) 
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Dense(units = n_neurons, input_shape=(dim_data,), bias_initializer="glorot_uniform")) 
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Dense(units = dim_data - 1, bias_initializer="glorot_uniform")) 

return model
```

Then I build my NN :

```
model = build_model(dim_data=3, n_neurons=10)
```

I then define a training step :

```
def train_step(model):

   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pos = [0,0]
    controle_actuel = model(np.array([0,pos[0],pos[1]]))
    loss_value = loss
   gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
   return loss_value, gradients
```

When I try this function , I get this error

```
input 0 of layer "dense_37" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (3,)
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to specify the input shape in the middle layers. Anyway, your input has shape `(3,)` but you have specified first layer input as `(3,1)`. try to change the first layer input shape like `input_shape=(3,)`.